# The Events Calendar, wp_query returning event date not published date

Tags: wp-query, events, the-events-calendar

I am using The Events Calendar (https://theeventscalendar.com/) I am running a custom WordPress loop, and looking to display the published date for each event. Inside the loop, I am using the_date();. However, this is displaying the event start date, not the published date. I've searched and searched and cannot find how to display the published date. Please help!

Comment: You will need to ask the plugin developers for support. Third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Sorry. I did ask the plugin developers, but no response.

Answer (score 0):

Support answered and said they didn't know how to get the published date, but they would ask their team. For anyone else looking for this answer, I finally found that I can use this to get this published date:

```
$date = mysql2date('F d, Y', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false);
```